# get form URL from a spreadsheet bound Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

In a spreadsheet script I want to send mail to users that will point them to the URL of a form that will let them enter data.  I have tried:

```
function test1(){

  var formID = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formUrl = DriveApp.getUrl(formID);
  sendMail(formUrl);
  return
}
```

This fails because the value of formID is allways NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are working in the Spreadsheet, you need to get the associated form from the Spreadsheet object (e.g. SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getFormUrl() ).

You will also need to send the mail message with the htmlBody optional parameter.

Here is a code sniplet:

```
function sendNotice(recipient){
  try{

    // either hardcode the folder id below
    var formStorageFolderId = '';

    // or programmatically get the folder from the spreadsheet parent
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var ssFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
    if(ssFolder.hasNext()){
      // assume there is only one parent folder
      formStorageFolderId = ssFolder.next().getId();
    }

    var formFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(formStorageFolderId);

    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
    var formId = '';
    while(files.hasNext()){
      // search for the form (is it the same name as the spreadsheet?)
      var file = files.next();
      var fileName = file.getName();
      var sheetName = ss.getName();
      if(fileName == sheetName){
        // matched names

        formId = file.getId();
        break;
      }
    }
    if(formId){
      var actualForm = FormApp.openById(formId);
      var formName = actualForm.getTitle();
      var formURL = actualForm.getPublishedUrl();

      var subject = "Please fill out form";
      // html mail message (needed for the link
      var mailBody = '<div><p>Please fill out the attached form<p>';
      mailBody += '<p><a href="' + formURL +'">' + formName + '</a>';

      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '',{htmlBody:mailBody});
    }

  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus that gets me a little closer.  However,  I now get the error "The api method 'getFormUrl' is not available yet in the new version of Google Sheets."  I guess I will have to hardcode the the URL into the spreadsheet for now.

Comment: @MalcL, my apologies, I should have verified the code sniplet.  I have modified my original posting to show a different way to get the published url.  You may need to adjust the logic, it is assuming that the form and spreadsheet have the same file name, and are stored in the same folder in Drive.

Comment: As of now, getFormUrl() works in new Sheets; but as noted [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29195006), it returns only one form Url. I added an answer for the case of multiple forms, which is partly based on yours but does not make assumptions about filenames.

Answer (score 5):

#### If there is one form linked to spreadsheet

Use

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // or openById, etc
var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();
```

to get its Url. If needed, `FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);` returns a pointer to the form, which allows any other methods.

#### Multiple forms linked to spreadsheet

There is no built-in method to return the list of forms linked to a given spreadsheet; this is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4481) in Apps Script issues tracker. A workaround is to search *all* forms ([as Cyrus Loree did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234181)), get the destination of each, and return the list of those where the destination is the spreadsheet of interest. This is how:

```
function linkedForms() {
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var formList = [];
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl(files.next().getUrl());
    try {
      if (form.getDestinationId() == ssId) {
        formList.push(form.getPublishedUrl());
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
  }
  return formList;
}
```

Remarks:

- I put `form.getDestinationId()` in a try block because this method throws an error what the form's destination spreadsheet happens to be deleted (instead of just returning `null`)
- To get the list of form Ids instead of Urls, use `form.getId()` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old question, but I'll still add an answer to whom it may concern. @user3717023's answer works fine, but for most use-cases, there's a better way.

Generally speaking, `Form` is connected to `Sheet`, not to `Spreadsheet` itself. So, one way to get all of the `Spreadsheet` forms is to go through the `Sheet`s of the `Spreadsheets`, and get their Form URL, like that:

```
function getFormsOfSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const formsUrls = [];

  for (const sheet of sheets) {
    const formUrl = sheet.getFormUrl();
    // getFormUrl() returns null if no form connected
    if (formUrl) {
      formsUrls.push(formUrl);
    }
  }
  
  return formsUrls;
}
```

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getformurl)

If this way is not optimal for you (e.g. you have way too many `Sheet`s in your `Spreadsheet` and only a few of them are linked to `Form`s), there's still a possibility that the `Form`s you need to capture are stored in the same `Folder`. In this case, there's no need to search through the whole `Drive` to capture them, you can use the same method, but with `Folder`:

```js
function linkedForms() {
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var formList = [];
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(yourFolderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var form = FormApp.openByUrl(files.next().getUrl());
    try {
      if (form.getDestinationId() == ssId) {
        formList.push(form.getPublishedUrl());
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
  }
  return formList;
}
```

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype)

Comment: TypeError: sheet.getFormUrl(...).getId is not a function

Comment: @arulselvan sure you can't get an ID of a URL - URL is a string, it can't have an ID. Where did you get it from?

Comment: That's a beautiful and important answer: search by each sheet. There's one more huge benefit: the event onFormSubmit sends a range property. Using range.getSheet(), voilà, we can get directly our range.getSheet().getFormUrl(). Thank you!!