# getFormUrl() in google spreadsheet return url only of last linked form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have two forms linked with one spreadsheet, one sheet for each form.
When I run such script

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss;
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Logger.log(ss.getFormUrl());
}
```

I will see only one url (as life shows url for the second form). Is there any way to get urls for all linked forms?

Comment: There is a way to do this using DriveApp: see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856005/)

Comment: Since August 2017, this is available through the 'sheet' object: sheet.getFormURL()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is currently missing in the API. There is an existing request on the issue tracker for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4481). Star that issue to follow it for the resolution.

Comment: Thanks! It's a pitty to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's an old question, but I'll still add an answer to whom it may concern.

Generally speaking, `Form` is connected to `Sheet`, not to `Spreadsheet` itself. So, one way to get all of the `Spreadsheet` forms is to go through the `Sheet`s of the `Spreadsheets`, and get their Form URL, like that:

```
function getFormsOfSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const formsUrls = [];

  for (const sheet of sheets) {
    const formUrl = sheet.getFormUrl();
    // getFormUrl() returns null if no form connected
    if (formUrl) {
      formsUrls.push(formUrl);
    }
  }
  
  return formsUrls;
}
```

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getformurl)

The other possible way is to get all of the `Form`s in the Drive or in the `Folder`, iterate through them to get their destination and compare it to your `Spreadsheet` ID, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37856005/2313004)