# Find Id of Form bound to "sheetname" in copy of spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a copy of a Google spreadsheet that contains forms associated with several sheets. I need to access the forms (of the copies) when running the code associated with each copy. Is there any way to do that?

Explication: Sheet1 of SS1 has a Form1, and Sheet2 has Form2. There is also Code1.
I make a copy of SS1: CSS1, which has CSheet1/CForm1, CSheet2/CForm2, and CCode1 (the names of the sheets don't actually change with the copying of course). I need the code in the copy, CSS1.CCode1, to be able to find CForm1 and CForm2. It will know they are associated with sheets named Sheet1 and Sheet2 in CSS1.
Please tell me this is possible :-) Thanks!

Note: there are many copies being made, this is a simplification. It should be obvious I can't use openById() or openByURL(), unless I've missed something. I can't figure out whether I could use getActiveForm(), since there'd be more than one form that's container-bound.

Comment: There is no method returning the form linked to a particular sheet. It's an [acknowledged issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4481) in Apps Script issues tracker, which you may want to star. The best I can do is to [get all forms linked to a spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37856005/), but which of them is linked to which sheet remains unknown.

Comment: Thank you, the post your pointed to me looks very promising! I assume form.getDestinationId returns a sheet not a spreadsheet, is that a mistake or am I missing something? I'll have to see how this works time-wise, there will be hundreds and perhaps thousands of forms on my drive. Could I limit it to a folder or something?

Comment: Alternatively, could there be any way to push the form's URL or Id to it's reporting sheet or elsewhere in the spreadsheet when the spreadsheet/form is copied/created? I can't quite wrap my head around it, but can imagine it as another path

Comment: Unfortunately, form.getDestinationId returns the Spreadsheet Id. Yes, it's stupid. There is also form.getDestinationType which suggests it could return something else, but in fact it always says Spreadsheet. Yes, you can limit the scope to a folder by calling [getFilesByType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype) on that folder.

Comment: Having the form URL written somewhere on the sheet receiving its data would be nice, but I can't think of a way to trigger this action when a spreadsheet gets copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've spent hours on this, including searching all over the Internet with no results.
I finally found a solution, but I'm too tired to make it formal and provide code, so maybe someone can add to this.
Here's what I found:
All the form URL's and the sheet IDs they are bound to are in the HTML code of the spreadsheet app.
Pressing F12 opens up the HTML editor, making it searchable.
So, let's make use of all that:

1. I wrote a little script that opened each of my forms (190 of them!!) and put the form's URL, filename, and creation date into spreadsheet columns (of course, add whatever else you may need). Ex. "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1sFEHY7xZ8mERPABCDjuFX_upPdXg9WA8eHuKRrFVOqI/edit?usp=drivesdk"
2. Searching the HTML code of the spreadsheet app for a snippet of any part of the URL from step 1 (ex. "FVOqI") will locate the  tag containing the information we're looking for.
3. Copying that tag's contents and pasting it into Word allows you to search it and clean it up. Search the Word text for that URL snippet again and you'll find the block containing the data you want.
   ex. 
   `[47296698,null,"1sFEHY7xZ8mABCDE74juFX_upPdXg9WA8eHuKRrFVOqI","1005701629"]],[47667827,[null,"1sFEHY7xZ8mABCDE74juFX_upPdXg9WA8eHuKRrFVOqI","1005701629",0.0]],[47296698,[null,"1V4BtJ7XAF2oVnlHGABCDEnXkKZdmg1vTMYjAX41RKYA","1245366039"]],[47667827,[null,"1V4BtJ7XAF2oVnlHGABCDEnXkKZdmg1vTMYjAX41RKYA","1245366039",0.0]]`

   and so on. Everything is duplicated for some reason.
4. Now you can extract the first string which is the form's URL and the next string which is the sheet ID it is bound to.

4a. I wrote a little code that runs through all the sheets in the spreadsheet and puts the ID's and names into columns. Matching the sheet ID's from step 4 to your spreadsheet ID's and matching the URL's from step 1 will give you the file name, and you'll know which form is bound to which sheet.

Again, I apologize for not being more thorough, but my bosses are coming for me and I've got to get this project finished.

Comment: Did you forget to share your script, or what is that forms link supposed to do? I can't open it. I wonder how much that could be automated Further. Also: isn't there some kind of breakdown that you aren't documenting? That is, after a file has been copied and there are multiple copies of the related code around, often opening the script editor will cause it to ask me which copy I want to edit, implying that all of them are linked to the spreadsheet... or something.